# Reading JSON from file into tidyjson

Tags: r, json, tidyverse

I'm trying to read json from the location below and create a tidy version using tidyjson.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysociety/parlparse/master/members/people.json

The guides for tidyjson don't mention how to read the file.  I've tried various ways including fromJSON, read_JSON, readJSON and read_lines but hit errors in each example.

e.g.

```
peopleJSON <- read_lines(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysociety/parlparse/master/members/people.json"))
people <- peopleJSON  %>% as.tbl_json

Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       {
                     (right here) ------^
```

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong or whether the issue is with the data.

Any help would be warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromJSON` from `jsonlite` returns a list of 4 dataframes.

```
data <- jsonlite::fromJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysociety/parlparse/master/members/people.json')

sapply(data, dim)

#     memberships organizations persons posts
#[1,]       45674            43   13902  2370
#[2,]          15             4       5     8
```

You can access individual dataframes with `data$memberships`, `data$organizations` etc.